# How to turn arg or string into User?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am making a command and I need to get a list of roles for a user, the problem is that an argument is a string and getMember() expects a User. How do I turn a string into a User or is there just a better way?

I have trouble shooted with my friends trying various methods. Honestly at this point I can't remember what we have tried.

```
else if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(MeatBotMain.prefix + "getuserroles")) {
            Guild server = event.getGuild();
            String userName = args[1];
            Member user = server.getMember(userName);
            List<Role> userRoles = user.getRoles();
        }
```

I wasn't expecting it to be so hard to get the mentioned user I thought it would just work first try.

Answer (score 0):

If you only has an username, which is not unique, the `Guild` class has methods:

```
List<Member> getMembersByName(String name, boolean ignoreCase);
List<Member> getMembersByNickname(String nickname, boolean ignoreCase);
List<Member> getMembersByEffectiveName(String name, boolean ignoreCase);
```

that you can try.